# Laravel mssql driver support

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel

I have been searching mssql driver for Laravel framework, but had no luck so far. I know Laravel has sqlsrv support for sql servers, but what I need is mssql connector (ones that have functions starting with 'mssql_').

We cannot use sqlsrv because most of our servers are MSSQL 2000, and sqlsrv doesn't provide support for these servers as far as I know. Also, MS does not provide sqlsrv driver for linux. (We are using freetds driver with manually compiled php 5.4.8 on Fedora 17 64-bit).

**My question is**

1. Is there any patch for mssql support in Laravel?
2. If not, which files should I create/modify to have mssql supported if it is ever possible?

I could use different framework that supports mssql as well, but I really like how Laravel handles everything. I didn't want to give up on Laravel just because it doesn't support mssql.

Comment: Laravel's database tools are designed to work with PDO, not with the native php database commands (mssql_).  If the sqlsrv drivers don't work for you, you might try an ODBC setup.  There are ODBC drivers for Laravel in various states of completion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems it does not include that driver... I believe you can setup it at laravel/database/connectors

Comment: Not only that, but also there seems to be more files related to database. `query/grammars/` and `schema/grammars` also seem related. I want to know exactly which files and functions I need to extend to get mssql working.