# Not getting connected to Sql Server 2012

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel-4

I am getting following error while connecting to Sql Server 2012 in Laravel 4

> PDOException SQLSTATE[IMSSP]: This extension requires the Microsoft
>   SQL Server 2012 Native Client ODBC Driver to communicate with SQL
>   Server. Access the following URL to download the Microsoft SQL Server
>   2012 Native Client ODBC driver for x86:
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=163712

As per this link 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc296170.aspx

I downloaded and installed these two files in `xampp/php/etc/ folder`

> php_sqlsrv_54_ts.dll
>
> php_pdo_sqlsrv_54_ts.dll

And added these two in the php.ini file. But still I am seeing the same error.

I am using windows 7 and xampp. Please help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Laravel mssql driver support](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15033069/laravel-mssql-driver-support)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I removed Xampp and installed Wamp (32 bit) server on my Windows 7, because after following almost every tutorial my xampp installation became unstable.

Following are the steps that resulted in successful connection to SQL SERVER 2012.

- Download Microsoft SQL Driver for PHP
  http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=20098
- Click on the exe to extract it copy below two dlls 
  Add Extensions in the D:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.4.4\bin\php.ini

  ```
  extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_54_ts.dll
  extension=php_sqlsrv_54_ts.dll
  ```
- After that I downloaded and installed this Microsoft Sql Server 2012 SP1 Feature Pack 
  http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=35580

  After this restart your computer.You should see these two blocks in your phpinof() output

[image]

[image]

thats it. Hope this will help someone.

Comment: This saved me from hours of more researching. THANK YOU.