# PHP 7.2 + sqlsrv + string(237) "SQLSTATE[IMSSP]: This extension requires the Microsoft ODBC Driver for SQL Server to communicate with SQL Server

Tags: php, sql-server, odbc, plesk, sqlsrv

I need to connect to **SQL Server from PHP 7.2 on PLESK CentOS 7 with sqlsrv**.

I have all I need - as far as I know.

1 - I have installed  `msodbcsql` package

2 - I have installed packages:

`unixODBC-devel make gcc-c++ gcc autoconf automake plesk-php7.2-devel libtool-ltdl.x86_64 libtool-ltdl-devel.x86_64`

3 - I have added `pdo_sqlsrv` and `sqlsrv` modules

4 - I reread PHP handlers

5 - I reread the components properties to make modules visible in GUI

6 - I have checked:
`/opt/plesk/php/7.2/bin/php -m | grep sqlsrv`

and I see:

```
pdo_sqlsrv
sqlsrv
```

7 - I have restarted the PHP-FPM master process to apply changes to FPM sites

8 - I have checked I have the ODBC driver in latest version:

> Package unixODBC-2.3.11-1.rh.x86_64 already installed and latest version

```
unixODBC 2.3.11
DRIVERS............: /etc/odbcinst.ini
SYSTEM DATA SOURCES: /etc/odbc.ini
FILE DATA SOURCES..: /etc/ODBCDataSources
USER DATA SOURCES..: /root/.odbc.ini
```

9 - I have checked and I have `ini` files for `php7.2` in path `/opt/plesk/php/7.2/etc/php.d: odbc.ini`

but still when trying to connect from script I see error:

> string(237) "SQLSTATE[IMSSP]: This extension requires the Microsoft ODBC Driver for SQL Server to communicate with SQL Server. Access the following URL to download the ODBC Driver for SQL Server for x64: [https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=163712"](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=163712%22)

My code to connect:

```php
$params = [
    "UID" => $username,
    "PWD" => $password,
    "Database" => $database,
    "TrustServerCertificate" => true
];
if(sqlsrv_connect($host, $params)) {
    echo "connected..";
} else {
    echo "Connection could not be established. DO not know why..sick!<br />";
    echo "<pre>";
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
    echo "</pre>";
}
```

That works on PHP8.0 on the same server (different webspace).

What am I missing?

Update - further info:

For debugging I have locked remote access to MS SQL server - to make sure if the problem is on Apache/www side or MS SQL.
The error doesn't change - so I am sure the problem is somewhere on web server - but no idea what is wrong..

Comment: How is MySQL also involved here?

Comment: @ThomA - what do you mean?

Comment: @ButcherFromHell You had put the mysql tag (which I removed).

Comment: @ThomA - oo sorry  haven't seen that - it must have been suggested tag that I misscliked. Thanks.

Comment: @Olivier - thanks.

Comment: I found that old post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25424708/sql-server-access-from-php-pdo-not-working-despite-driver-installed-enabled/46245990#46245990 - it is somehow connected with issue

Answer (score 0):

I finally made it work.

What was wrong?

> step 1 -  I have installed `msodbcsql` package

and I did - I took info about it from [here](https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/12377482190999--How-to-install-the-sqlsrv-extension-for-the-Plesk-PHP-handlers-?sort_by=votes) .

```bash
# curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/rhel/7/prod.repo > /etc/yum.repos.d/mssql-release.repo
# yum remove unixODBC-utf16 unixODBC-utf16-devel
# ACCEPT_EULA=Y yum install msodbcsql18
```

There is info to install **Microsoft ODBC 18 (msodbcsql18) and sqlsrv-5.8.1 for PHP 7.2 - and that will not work together.**

It was `ver 18 - Microsoft ODBC 18` . In my research I went again [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/system-requirements-for-the-php-sql-driver?view=sql-server-ver16#php) - and find out that **php driver 5.8.1 will not work with Microsoft ODBC 18.**
Have missed that before.

So I have installed previous `Microsoft ODBC 17`

```bash
# curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/rhel/7/prod.repo | sudo tee /etc/yum.repos.d/mssql-release.repo

# sudo yum remove unixODBC-utf16 unixODBC-utf16-devel #to avoid conflicts
# sudo ACCEPT_EULA=Y yum install -y msodbcsql17

# sudo ACCEPT_EULA=Y yum install -y mssql-tools
# echo 'export PATH="$PATH:/opt/mssql-tools/bin"' >> ~/.bashrc
# source ~/.bashrc

# sudo yum install -y unixODBC-devel
```

as MS advised [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16&tabs=redhat18-install%2Credhat17-install%2Cdebian8-install%2Credhat7-13-install%2Crhel7-offline), then restart of apache and I finally got connected ! :)

Conclusion:

Double check versions of drivers to be sure that they can work together. As it turned out - it is very important.